# PHP variable across two pages

Tags: php, ajax

Sorry if the title is inaccurate, but I need help syncing a variable across two pages, when the second is loading with ajax (Instant Messanging)

I need it to fetch a page with ajax, just if I define a variable earlier on in the same document it doesn't apply to the ajax page (I can't use `include`)

```
page1.php

<?php $variable = 'apples'; ?>
<script src="script.js"></script> <!--Contains ajax for page2.php-->

<div id="gets_parsed_here"></div>
```

And it uses ajax to get page2.php

```
page2.php

<?php echo $variable; ?>
```

This isn't my actual code, but it's similar to what it should do.

Any help would be appreciated a lot.

Comment: You can't solve it in this way because the javascript ajax request will be handled in the async fashion. You can however use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php) to do the request on the server side or do a third request after the second one.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using COOKIES/SESSION.

for example:

page1.php

```
<?php
@session_start();
    //if you get your variable from a remote page you should place it this var defination bellow:
<?php $_SESSION['keyName'] = 'apples'; ?>
<script src="script.js"></script> <!--Contains ajax for page2.php-->

<div id="gets_parsed_here"></div>
```

page2.php

```
<?php 
@session_start();
echo $_SESSION['keyName']; 
?>
```

`SESSION` can be accssed from every page in the same server with no code related.
you just have to enable it by using `session_start();`

- really reccomend to add `@` before `session_start()` due to security reason.

you can read more about `SESSION` on [PHP.NET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is how to pass a variable from page1.php to page2.php, when page1.php calls page2.php via AJAX.

As your script is in an external JS file, there are 2 steps involved:

- Get the variable in Javascript, so script.js can access it.  How you do this depends on what you're actually doing, but here's a simple example.  Add the following somewhere on page1.php before you include script.js:

  ```
  <script>
      var fruit = <?php echo json_encode($variable); ?>;
  </script>
  ```

  Alternatively it might make more sense to read the variable from wherever it already appears on the page, eg (with jQuery):

  ```
  var fruit = $('#someID).val();
  ```
- Pass the Javascript variable on to page2.php in the AJAX request.  You can do that by passing it as a GET or POST parameter.  You haven't shown how you're doing the AJAX call in script.js, but here's how you can do it in jQuery (this is GET):

  ```
  $.ajax({
      url: 'http://your-site/page2.php',
      data: { 'fruit': fruit },
      success: function(resp) {
          // AJAX is done, use the response
      }
  });
  ```

  This issues a request to `http://your-site/page2.php?fruit=apples`.  And as you know from PHP 101 you can access the value of fruit in page2.php like:

  ```
  echo $_GET['fruit'];
  ```

  If you are using a framework use it's preferred method of accessing the input request parameters instead of accessing $_GET directly.

Comment: You should do `var fruit = <?php echo json_encode($variable); ?>;`, not just naked echo in quotes.

Comment: Quotes need to be removed now, because that's part of `json_encode` work. If you leave quotes, it will break your code, unless `$variable` is a number. If it is a number indeed, you will end with a number being converted to string. All other cases will be disastrous :)

Comment: Doh! It's been a long day here ;-)  Thanks.